# MSP430G2553: continuous ADC10 sampling (with interrupt)

Tags: msp430, texas-instruments

I wrote a small program to continuously sample the internal temperature sensor of the MSP430G2553 based on the ADC10 interrupt. My code, however, does not do that. It triggers the interrupt (only) once, it populates the first index of the array,  and then it stops. What am I missing?

```
    #include <msp430g2553.h>

/**
 * main.c
 * Use ADC module to read the value of the MCU's internal temperature sensor
 * and dump those values into an array.
 */

volatile unsigned counter = 0;
volatile unsigned temparr[20];

void main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;                                           // Stop WDT

    ADC10CTL0 = SREF_1 + ADC10SHT_3 + REFON + ADC10ON + ADC10IE + MSC;  // Set ADC module
    ADC10CTL1 = CONSEQ_0 + INCH_10 + ADC10DIV_7;                        // Set ADC module
    ADC10DTC0 = ADC10CT;                                                // Set ADC module

    ADC10CTL0 |= ENC + ADC10SC;                                         // Start ADC + sampling

    __enable_interrupt();

}

#pragma vector=ADC10_VECTOR
__interrupt void ADC10_IRS(void)
{
    while (ADC10CTL1 & BUSY);                                           // Give time to the ADC to settle

    if (counter < 20) {
        temparr[counter] = ADC10MEM;
        counter++;
    }

    else {
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @HeadCode 22.2.10: "The ADC10IFG flag is automatically reset when the interrupt request is serviced."

Comment: Logically, your program stops when it returns from `main`. Never do that in an embedded program.

Comment: @CL. that would be the case if the ADC10CTL(0 & 1) registries would not be set to continuous sampling. I think I managed to make it work, I'm posting code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #include <msp430g2553.h>

/**
 * main.c
 * Use ADC module to read the value of the MCU's internal temperature sensor
 * and dump those values into an array.
 */

volatile unsigned counter = 0;
volatile unsigned temparr[20];

void main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;                                           // Stop WDT

    ADC10CTL0 = SREF_1 + ADC10SHT_3 + REFON + ADC10ON + ADC10IE + MSC;  // Set ADC module
    ADC10CTL1 = CONSEQ_2 + INCH_10 + ADC10DIV_7;                        // Set ADC module
    ADC10DTC0 = ADC10CT;                                                // Set ADC module

    ADC10CTL0 |= ENC + ADC10SC;

    __enable_interrupt();

}

#pragma vector=ADC10_VECTOR
__interrupt void ADC10_IRS(void)
{
    //while (ADC10CTL1 & BUSY);                                           // Give time to the ADC to settle

    if (counter < 20) {
        temparr[counter] = ADC10MEM;
        counter++;
    }

    else {
        counter = 0;
        ADC10CTL0 &= ~(ENC + ADC10SC);
    }
}
```

It seems this was a problem with the debugger. After running the code a few times, it just started working :S. I'm using the MSP-FET Flash Tool connected directly into an MSP430G2553 chip via Spy-By-Wire. I know a few TI users have reported problems with this unit after the latest firmware update (CCS8).